Stripe Webhook "No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload" error on server but works locally
I'm having an issue with Stripe webhooks. Locally, everything works fine, but on my server, I keep receiving the following error:

No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?
If a webhook request is being forwarded by a third-party tool, ensure that the exact request body, including JSON formatting and new line style, is preserved.
Learn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration examples for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

I understand that the data should be passed raw into the route without any modifications. I have verified that the request reaches the correct route since the error only occurs at that endpoint, and I am using the Stripe library for handling webhooks.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
const express = require('express');
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // Check if the request is for the '/webhook' endpoint
  console.log(req.originalUrl);
  if (req.originalUrl === '/api/webhook') {
    // Continue to the next middleware or route handler
    next();
  } else {
    // If not a '/webhook' request, use the express.json() middleware
    express.json()(req, res, next);
  }
});

app.post('/api/webhook', bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), async (req, res) => {
  const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY;
  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  try {
    if (!endpointSecret) {
      return res.status(400).send('Webhook Error: Missing secret key');
    }

    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, sig, endpointSecret);

    switch (event.type) {
      case 'checkout.session.completed':
        const session = event.data.object;
        if (!session.metadata) return;

        const metaData = JSON.parse(session.metadata.invoiceInfo.toString());
        if (session.payment_status === 'paid') {
          const redisData = await RedisManager.Get(`${RedisKey.StripPayment}_${session.id}_${metaData.userId}_${metaData.invoiceId}`);
          const data = await Unitofwork.invoiceService.GetInvoiceByIdForPayment(redisData?.id);

          const comission = data.platformComission;
          let credit = ((data.creditPercent || 0) / 100) * comission;
          let platformComission = (comission + (Number(data.networkFee) * Number(data.netwrokExchangeRate))) + credit;

          let amount = await this.calculatePrice(data.price, data.discount);

          const hash = await this.transferSameToken(redisData?.payBy._id, data.reciverAddressWallet, amount, platformComission, true);

          if (typeof hash == 'object') {
            data.transactionHash = hash.transactionTxn;
            data.platformTransactionHash = hash.platformTxn;
            data.message = 'invoice.message_successfull';
            data.status = InvoiceStatus.Success;
            await new CreditUtil().updateUserCredit(data, redisData?.payBy._id);
            data.save();

            await CpayNotification.sendNotification(data, true);

            await RedisManager.Remove(`${RedisKey.StripPayment}_${session.id}_${metaData.userId}_${metaData.invoiceId}`);
          }
        }
        break;
      case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
        break;
      case 'payment_method.attached':
        const paymentMethod = event.data.object;
        break;
      default:
        console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
    }

    res.status(200).send();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

Additional Context

The code works perfectly on my local machine. I suspect that Nginx
might be altering the request body before it reaches my application
on the server.

How can I ensure that the raw request body from Stripe is passed unchanged to my application? What configurations or settings do I need to adjust in Nginx to solve this issue?
Edit:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gateway-pay.com;

    if ($host = gateway-pay.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cloudflare-csr.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cloudflare-key.pem;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'xxxxx';

    # Security headers
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";

    # Uncomment if you want to enforce HSTS
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    location / {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' ;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*' ;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' ;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always ;
            return 204;
        }

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
    }

    location /api {
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' ;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' '*' ;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' ;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always ;
            return 204;
        }

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/socket.io;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /api/webhook {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # Disable request buffering to ensure the raw request is passed through
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    # Uncomment and adjust if needed
    # location /currency-* {
    #     proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    #     proxy_http_version 1.1;
    #     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    #     proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    #     proxy_set_header Host $host;
    # }
}


What is the configuration of your nginx? are you using compress middleware like gzip? Have you had the chance to double check the webhook secret and the API key in your deployment that are correct?

@os4m37 question updated , plesae check it

Did you double check that you are using the correct webhook endpoint secret after adding it from your dashboard  https://docs.stripe.com/webhooks#endpoint-secrets?

@os4m37 webhook for local is different than live server r?

Yes you need to create a webhook endpoint and use it's webhook secret

@os4m37 where can i find webhook secret in strip site?

You can find it on the Webhook endpoint's page in Stripe (devs>webhooks>{webhook}). You'll have to reveal it, the string starts with whsec_

@Lucky2501 im using this whsec_ but it dosent work in live server
